# Indirect formula for named range

Tags: excel, sum, excel-indirect

I have a named ranged called Mgt1October2014 which I am looking to SUM.

Each of these elements are in three separate cells

- A1: `Mgt1`
- A2: `October`
- A3: `2014`

I'm trying to use this indirect formula, but it is returning ref.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(A1&A2&A3))
```

Sure it's a simple one, but I can't work out what it should be!

Comment: Just tested it; works for me... You will have to give us enough information to reproduce the problem, else we can't help. Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

That will work if Mgt1October2014 is a fixed range - is it a **dynamic** range? You can't use INDIRECT with a dynamic named range

Comment: No, it's a 3-D named reference. Is that causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, you can't use those with INDIRECT either - what are you trying to do, are you summing the same range across multiple sheets. Does the range change based on the name or does that change the sheets?